# Better way to develop a remote database driven android app?

Tags: java, android

i have a wordpress blog hosted over my personal shared hosting.Now i want to develop an android app for that blog so the users can use the mobile app to see what i am writing on my blog.

Like for example you can take mashable.com android app.

so basically i have experience in programming android aap but i am just asking this so i can code it in a better way.

i have 3 idea to do this now:

1.Use rss feed of my blog and parse it and display the contents but it has a issue that rss only display most latest contents.So whether i need to store the feed contents timely on android device so a user can view the previous most content also.

But i think it's not a good idea because it will unnecessarily  increase the size of database and make diff copies on every device.

2.Just simply use complete java code to pull data from my web mysql database as per the user request and just display it over the screen without storing it locally on android device.

3.Develop some sort of API solution on my web server then send the data in json or xml format so i can use it on my android device(via java) without bothering to connecting to mysql server as a core part because that part already done by on web server and my api already sending data in required format.

So these are 3 idea i have now.So please suggest me a better one form these three or you can give any other idea.

I am asking this question because previously i never programmed this sort of mobile aap where i need to pull the data from remote server.

-Thanks

Comment: why anyone -1 it?At least put a comment

Comment: Hey ! @Peeyush ! I understood your question. Valid point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply install [WordPress Mobile Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/screenshots/) to display Mobile site of your wordpress blog/site 
Or
You can check this link to find out other plugins: [11 Ways to Create a Mobile Friendly WordPress Site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/11-ways-to-create-a-mobile-friendly-wordpress-site/)

Now, If you want to create an app then you can simply implement it by using **WebView**.

Comment: thanks this is also one way of doing that.So i will try it and hope it will work as per my requirements.If it will not work as per the requirements of the project  then i decided to go with via developing an API for that blog.Any ways thanks for the answer,i came to know about something new.:-)